# SQL GROUP BY does not return the correct result for combination of two table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm new In SQL and I'm in trouble. I have two tables:
`1. TopStock : Id |RuyeId| Code |ModelId|Quantity|ColorId`
`.............: 1 | 1019 |290105|  44   |  100   |  23`
`.............: 2 | 1019 |290105|  44   |  150   |  23`
`.............: 3 | 1019 |290105|  44   |  400   |  19`
`.............: 4 | 1019 |290105|  44   |  50    |  23`
`.............: 4 | 1018 |280102|  21   |  800   |  14`

`2. DownStock : Id|KafiId| Code |Quantity|ColorId`
`.............: 1 | 1005 | 2901 |  200   |  21`

---

**This is my scenario:** `TopStock` can combine with `DownStock` if `DownStock`'s `Code` is equal to first 4 number in `TopStock`'s `Code`.
I want a query that shows sum quantity of each `TopStock`s `GROUP BY: ModelId,ColorId` and sum quantity of DownStocks that possible to combine with it.

**This is my query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(top.Quantity) as Quantity, MAX(top.Code) as Code
MAX(top.ColorId) as ColorId, MAX(top.ModelId) as ModelId, MAX(top.RuyeId) as RuyeId,
SUM(down.Quantity) as DownQuantity
    FROM TopStock as top JOIN DownStock as down ON top.Code like '%'+down.Code+'%'
        WHERE top.Status = 0
            GROUP BY top.ModelId, top.ColorId, top.Code, down.Code
```

I want this result:
`Quantity| Code |ColorId|ModelId|RuyeId|DownQuantity`
`.  300  |290105|   23  |  44   | 1019 |  200`
`.  400  |290105|   19  |  44   | 1019 |  200`

In fact `DownQuantity` should be sum of possible `DownStock` quantity for each `GROUP BY`ed `TopStock` item. But query return this:
`Quantity| Code |ColorId|ModelId|RuyeId|DownQuantity`
`.  300  |290105|   23  |  44   | 1019 |  600 -> (3*200)`
`.  400  |290105|   19  |  44   | 1019 |  200`

Problem : `3*200` because I have 3 `TopStock` row with same `ColorId` and `ModelId`. I just want 200 no 600. can anyone fix this?

Comment: You are grouping by `top.ColorId`, but also selecting `MAX(top.ColorId)` (same with the other grouped by attributes). This doesn't make sense.

Comment: @HoneyBadger I delete these selections but not fixed

Comment: your dbms name please

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all the uses of `MAX` , you're grouping by the columns, no reason to make an aggregation function on them as there will only be 1 value. Also, don't use both distinct and group by. I also joined to a summed table to avoid the duplicates in the join

```
SELECT SUM(top.Quantity) as Quantity,top.Code, top.ColorId, top.ModelId,  
       top.RuyeId, max(down.Quantity) as DownQuantity
FROM TopStock top 
JOIN (SELECT down.code, sum(down.quantity) as quantity FROM DownStock down
      GROUP BY down.code) down
 ON top.Code like '%'+down.Code+'%'
WHERE top.Status = 0
GROUP BY top.ModelId, top.ColorId, top.Code, down.Code
```

Comment: this query is amazing and correct. Just I Group down.Code inside Join select. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try like below by using row_number() window finction

```
with t1 as
 (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by ModelId,ColorId order by ColorId desc) rn
 from TopStock
 ) ,t2 as
(
 select t1.* from t1 where t1.rn<=2
) 
 select top.Code, top.ColorId, top.ModelId,  
       top.RuyeId, 
      SUM(top.Quantity) as Quantity,
      max(down.Quantity) as DownQuantity,
      from t2 top join DownStock down
      on top.Code like '%'+down.Code+'%'
      group by top.Code, top.ColorId, top.ModelId,  
       top.RuyeId
```

Comment: I write it and got some wrong results that cause maybe I can't manage this. because this is more than my abilities!